# R: Remove Counties with >3 NA's in Yield column , and use na.spline for counties with < 3 NA's

Tags: r, if-statement, na, spline, subset

I have a data.frame "df" with 5 columns: "year", "state", "county", "fips" (state-county identifier), "yield".

A number of counties contain `NA` for yield. I have initially eliminated the counties with any `NA` value through the code:

```
Data <- df %>% group_by(fips) %>% filter(!any(is.na(Yield)))
```

I now need to only eliminate those counties contain more than 3 NA's. Hence, NA>3

For those counties with `NA` =< 3, I use the `spline` function:

```
v <- na.spline(df$Yield)
df$Yield <- v
```

So far I have the following for removing all counties with `NA`>3 and using spline to fill the `NA`'s for the remaining shire:

```
if(length(df$Yield[is.na(df$Yield))<3){
na.spline(df$Yield)
}
}else{
df %>% group_by(fips) %>% filter(!any(is.na(Yield)))
}
```

This is clearly not working. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider to provide a small example dataset with expected output based on that example

Comment: Something like this: `df %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(is3NA=ifelse(sum(is.na(Yield))>3,"Include","Exclude")) %>% filter(is3NA=="Incude")` please provide an example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) 
df %>% 
   group_by(fips) %>%
   filter(sum(is.na(Yield))<3) %>% 
   mutate(Yield=na.spline(Yield))
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, .SD[sum(is.na(Yield))<=3] , fips][,Yield:= na.spline(Yield) ,fips][]
```

Or using `base R`

```
transform(subset(df, ave(is.na(Yield), fips, FUN=sum)<3), Yield=na.spline(Yield))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(29)
df <- data.frame(fips= sample(LETTERS[1:4], 30, replace=TRUE), 
     Yield= as.numeric(sample(c(NA,0:3), 30, replace=TRUE)), 
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```